# Dozer: Map class containing instance variable of itself

Tags: java, dozer

I've been googling and trying to find an example dozer xml configuration which maps a class having instance variable of itself. For example -

```
Public class A {
    String var1;
    int var2;
    List<A> var3;
}
```

into this class -

```
Public class B {
    String var1;
    int var2;
    List<B> var3;
}
```

From the documentation http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/mappings.html it looks like i don't need to define any configuration and dozer will itself map class A into class B (From dozer documentation - Explicit xml mapping for 2 classes is not required if all the field mapping between src and dest object can be performed by matching on attribute name (sic)).

But i am unsure if this will work. I am facing problem while setting up dozer in my project so i am not able to test it.

Please suggest how the above class A can be converted into class B using dozer?

Comment: This will work as it is because Source bean and Destination bean are having same variable names

Comment: Thanks. Will add comment after testing it.